# Errors: histogramme

Tags: javascript

In a factory a printer prints labels for boxes. The printer uses colors which, for the sake of simplicity, are named with letters from a to z (except letters u, w, x or z that are for errors).

The colors used by the printer are recorded in a control string. For example a control string would be `aaabbbbhaijjjm` meaning that the printer used three times color a, four times color b, one time color h then one time color a... and so on.

Sometimes there are problems: lack of colors, technical malfunction and a control string is produced e.g. `uuaaaxbbbbyyhwawiwjjjwwxym` where errors are reported with letters u, w, x or z.

You have to write a function hist which given a string will output the errors as a string representing a histogram of the encountered errors.

Format of the output string:

letter (error letters are sorted in alphabetical order) in a field of 2 characters, a white space, number of error for that letter in a field of 6, as many "*" as the number of errors for that letter and "\r".

The string has a length greater or equal to one and contains only letters from a to z.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function hist(s) {
  var regex = /[uwxz]/g;
  var tab = s.match(regex);
  var nbrex = 0;
  var nbrez = 0;
  var nbreu = 0;
  var nbrew = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (tab[i] === "z") {
      nbrez = nbrez + 1
    } else if (tab[i] === "x") {
      nbrex = nbrex + 1
    } else if (tab[i] === "u") {
      nbreu = nbreu + 1
    } else if (tab[i] === "w") {
      nbrew = nbrew + 1
    }
  }
  return "u  " + nbreu + "     " + "*".repeat(nbreu) + "w  " + nbrew + "     " + "*".repeat(nbrew) + "x  " + nbrex + "      " + "*".repeat(nbrex) + "z " + nbrez + " " + "*".repeat(nbrez)
}
```

Testing string:

```
tpwaemuqxdmwqbqrjbeosjnejqorxdozsxnrgpgqkeihqwybzyymqeazfkyiucesxwutgszbenzvgxibxrlvmzihcb
Actual:
 u  3     ***w  4     ****x  6      ******z 6 ******
Expect:
 u  3     ***
w  4     ****
x  6     ******
z  6     ******
Expected: 'u  3     ***\rw  4     ****\rx  6     ******\rz  6     ******', instead got: 'u  3     ***w  4     ****x  6      ******z 6 ******'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your post such that it is easier to read. Please try to put code in code blocks as much as possible.

Note the last line of your output:

```
Expected: 'u  3     ***\rw  4     ****\rx  6     ******\rz  6     ******', instead got: 'u  3     ***w  4     ****x  6      ******z 6 ******'
```

If we align the two values here, we can easily see what is going on:

```
Expected:    'u  3     ***\rw  4     ****\rx  6     ******\rz  6     ******'
instead got: 'u  3     ***w  4     ****x  6      ******z 6 ******'
```

It is clear that the string comparison is failing because of whitespace characters. Specifically, you used spaces and a carriage-return character in your code. Please note that string comparisons are strict: You have to exactly match every character, even the ones you cannot see (which are the spaces and carriage-return characters).

--

I suspect the carriage-return is introduced by your `repeat()` call, but I cannot be sure since you did not include that code. I even suspect that your actual value is correct and you're missing the "\r" in the expected value of your test, since your assignment mentions the "\r" character.